Combinations from itertools behaving weird
I need to identify pairs of subsets of the same size such that they are disjoint and that if we order the sets A={a_1<a_2<...<a_m} and B{b_1<b_2<...<b_m} then for every i=1,...,m a_i<b_i.
Here's my code:
n=7
cont=0
for m in range(2,n//2+1):
    combs=combinations(list(range(n)),m)
    combs=[set(comb) for comb in combs]
    print(combs)
    pairs=[(comb1,comb2) for comb1 in combs for comb2 in combs if comb1.intersection(comb2)==set()]
    pairs=[pair for pair in pairs if npmin(list(pair[0]))<npmin(list(pair[1]))]
    flag=True
    for pair in pairs:
        l1=list(pair[0])
        l2=list(pair[1])
        l1.sort()
        l2.sort()
        flag=True
        for n in range(m):
            flag=flag and l1[n]<l2[n]
        if not flag:
            cont+=1
cont

The expected output for this case, n=7, would be 70.
But, here's the thing, for the second iteration, m=3, the list combs is empty, so that for m=3 cont stays the same value, and the code then outputs a 35. I can't understand why. Any help is welcomed!

Can you add inputs and expected outputs?

You overwrite n inside the loop, so the second iteration isn't passing the parameters you expect to combinations()...

Use more descriptive variable names and you're less likely to reuse them improperly like this.

It's unclear what you're trying to do.
However, I made a few changes, that might help.
First, you can use SortedSet() so that you don't have to sort() every time.
Your question
For m == 3, it prints
combs

[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 5), (0, 1, 6), (0, 2, 3), (0,
2, 4), (0, 2, 5), (0, 2, 6), (0, 3, 4), (0, 3, 5), (0, 3, 6), (0, 4,
5), (0, 4, 6), (0, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6),
(1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2,
3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (3, 4,
5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]

Right?


I guess you don't want the same var names for n, combs and pairs.


from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet


def f(n):
    cont = 0
    for m in range(2, n // 2 + 1):
        if m > n:
            continue

        combs = combinations(list(range(n)), m)
        # if m == 3:
        #     print(list(combs))
        #     break
        scombs = [set(comb) for comb in combs]
        pairs = [(comb1, comb2) for comb1 in scombs for comb2 in scombs if comb1.intersection(comb2) == SortedSet()]
        spairs = [pair for pair in pairs if np.min(list(pair[0])) < np.min(list(pair[1]))]
        for l1, l2 in spairs:
            flag = True
            l1, l2 = list(l1), list(l2)
            for i in range(m):
                flag = flag and l1[i] < l2[i]
            if not flag:
                cont += 1
    return cont


print(f(7))


Outputs
70
Note

Make sure you're passing the correct n (inclusive) to combinations, if that's what you want:

combs = combinations(list(range(n + 1)), m)


You also forgot to add if m > n: continue.

